# Get the value of a select element into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the price value (after the " - ") to display in a div with the id of "price" and update as the select element is changed.

```
<select id="product-select" name="">
    <option value="1">Product Name / Yellow / S - ISK 2.500</option>
    <option value="2">Product Name / Red / M - ISK 2.550</option>
    <option value="3">Product Name / Red / S - ISK 2.300</option>
    <option value="4">Product Name / Pink / S - ISK 3.500</option>
    <option value="5">Product Name / Green / M - ISK 6.500</option>
</select>

<div id="price">+ PRICE HERE +</div>
```

I've tried couple of things but i can only get the full name value, not just the price. Anyone able to help ?.

Comment: _I've tried couple of things_ Show us the code.

Comment: Is OP the one down-voting everyone?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write change event for select and append the selected price value to div:

```
$('#product-select').change(function(){
  $('#price').html($(this).find(':selected').text().split('-')[1]);
}).change();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/00z0138s/)**

Comment: Do remember that Stack Overflow isn't a *do my work for me* website. Adding to that, OP claims that they've tried a couple of things, how can you be sure that they haven't tried this already?

Comment: Of course, i wasn't asking for that just a little help. This works great!, thank you Milind.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: it looks OP has not tried anything from what he/she has posted.

Comment: Enough with spoon feeding.

Comment: @MelanciaUK: you should rather downvote question due to its poor quality and not the answer.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are able to retrieve the value from the drop down, which is a good start. The next thing you will want to do is to parse just the price and leave the rest. It seems like you have a special format, so you can try to first find the dash, then use that index and extract everything from there on till the end of the string.

To solve your issue that you continuously want to update the price label depending on what the user has selected, you can listen for that specific `onchange` event and [Execute a JavaScript when a user changes the selected option of a  element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp).

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
$('#product-select').on('change', function(e) {
  v = e.target.outerHTML.match(/\- (ISK.*)\<\/o/i);
  console.log(v[1])
  $("#price").html(v[1])           
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="product-select" name="">
    <option value="1">Product Name / Yellow / S - ISK 2.500</option>
    <option value="2">Product Name / Red / M - ISK 2.550</option>
    <option value="3">Product Name / Red / S - ISK 2.300</option>
    <option value="4">Product Name / Pink / S - ISK 3.500</option>
    <option value="5">Product Name / Green / M - ISK 6.500</option>
</select>

<div id="price">+ PRICE HERE +</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many things you can do.  A quick simple way would be a split:

```
var str = value.split("-");//value is the full name you said you got
var price = str[1].trim();//price will now be the decimal value you want
document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = price;//set the price
```

Note that this isnt the only way and also the variable `value` that I used represents the full name that you got.  I didn't know if you wanted to change the way you got your value or not.